# overloading '>' as a non member function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm trying to write a program where I can compare two employees gross pay with an overloaded greater than operator. In order to get gross pay I have a member function that returns the gross pay. For some reason whenever I go to compare the two gross pays I get:

> Error 1   error C2662: '`double employeeclass::Employee::grosspay(void)`' : cannot convert '`this`' pointer from '`const employeeclass::Employee`' to '`employeeclass::Employee &`'

and

> 2 IntelliSense: the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function object type is: `const employeeclass::Employee`

I have included the segments of code that are giving me the issues.

The .cpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
#include "Employee.h"
namespace employeeclass {
    bool operator> (const Employee &e1, const Employee &e2) {
        if (e1.grosspay() > e2.grosspay())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

The .h file

```
namespace employeeclass {
    class Employee {
        friend bool operator> (const Employee &e1, const Employee &e2);
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like the `grosspay()` function is not marked `const`

Comment: BTW `if ( X ) return true; else return false;` can be better expressed as `return X;`

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), most importantly we need to  see the declaration of `Employee::grosspay`.

Comment: `const objects` can access `const member functions`. `e1` & `e2` are const objects and they are trying to access `non-const` member function `grosspay()`. So make `grosspay()` a const member function as expressed by @M.M

Answer (score 1):

Add const to header and cpp files for grosspay()

```
double employeeclass::Employee::grosspay(void) const;
```

The const specifier ensures the instance to use the function in a const declaration. Basically, const means this function is not going to make changes and is read only.